# How can I solve a system of 3 equations that use logs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, systems-of-equations

I'm having a bit of trouble solving this system of equations. What would be a good way of solving for the three variables in a question like this? I've tried many different ways of substituting or eliminating parts of this system but I can't seem to get on the right path with this one.

```
(logx)(logy) - 3log5y - log8x = -4
(logy)(logz) - 4log5y - log 16z = 4
(logz)(logx) - 4log8x -3log625z = -18
```

Comment: $\log(5y)=\log\, 5+\log \, y$ etc. So write these as a system of  equations in the variables $u=\log\, x,v=\log\, y,w=\log\, z$.

Comment: define new variables $a= \log x,$ $ b = \log y,$

Comment: Here is how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).